# Pyathena in Jupyter Notebook Can't find aws config file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-athena, pyathena

I'm using a jupyter notebook, and I'm trying to query AWS athena using PyAthena module, via the notebook.

My first line in the project is:

```py
athena = pyathena.connect(profile_name="NAME")
```

which works in any other platform on my computer (iPython, Pycharm..) but doesn't work on the Jupyter Notebook, and returns:

```py
ProfileNotFound: The config profile (core) could not be found
```

I tried changing the env variable like so: `!set AWS_CONFIG_FILE="~/.aws/config"` but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your notebook running under the correct user? Maybe its running as root or some other user, and your profile is created for a regular user?

Comment: only one user on the computer, and not running as root..

Comment: can you confirm the user name, `!whoami`? `pyathena` works normally in notebook. So if its corrent user, you  must somehow misconfigured your notebook.

Comment: it says "/bin/sh: 1: whoami: Permission denied"

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are confusing the role of an AWS config and credential file (see the docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html)

- You should attempt first to authenticate using the AWS CLI in bash with a very simple command to confirm your named profile is setup correctly.

> For reference, you can use the `!` (exclamation point) inside of a Jupyter Notebook cell to run bash commands. For reference see Jupyter Magics here: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#line-magics

```py
!aws sts get-caller-identity --profile <YOUR_NAMED_PROFILE_HERE>
```

Assuming that returns a successful response, you should be able to use PyAthena like the following:

```py
from pyathena import connect

conn = connect(profile_name='<YOUR_NAMED_PROFILE_HERE>',
               work_group='<YOUR_WORKGROUP_HERE>', 
               region_name='<YOUR_REGION_HERE>')
```

> optionally you can do either `work_group` or the S3 bucket output location as `s3_staging_dir`

If that still fails, it's likely because you did not setup your named profile correctly in `~/.aws/credentials`